# How to import a module dynamically in Next.js from the same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have several modules of styled components in a file exported which I want to dynamically import into another file.

I learned to import a module we have to do this

```
const Heading = dynamic(
  () => import("./style").then((module) => module.Heading),
   {
     ssr: false,
   }
 );
```

How can I import all the modules at once instead of importing them separately for every module from the same file?

I want to achieve something like this, but it gives me an error to load all components in a single import

```
 const {Heading , CustomError }= dynamic(
  () => import("./style").then((module) => module),
   {
     ssr: false,
   }
 );
```

Comment: `dynamic` is only meant for single components. Nextjs will do some behind-the-scene magic to make it a loadable component (wrap it inside a custom component of theirs) so you can't load several components that way. If you're worried about bundling / loading, you should look into webpack rather than nextjs itself, but I probably wouldn't recommend it unless you actually notice some performance issues.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `dynamic` doesn't necessarily need a default export. The first code snippet in this question will work, and it uses a named export.

Comment: Thanks @Sheraff! I shouldn't have inferred that from `React.lazy`'s requirement. In fact, the docs I linked even show how to do a named export. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I don't use Next.js (yet?). But trying to help anyway:

I think the nature of [`dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) is that it creates and returns a single component facade when you call it, so you'll have to make multiple calls to `dynamic`. But that doesn't mean you have to repeat everything. Unless `dynamic` is a pseudo-function that's replaced at build time, you can give yourself a helper to do the heavy lifting:

```
const dynamicStyle = (name) => dynamic(
    () => import("./style").then((module) => module[name]),
    { ssr: false }
);
```

Then at least each component is simpler and not (that) repetitive:

```
const Heading = dynamicStyle("Heading");
const CustomError = dynamicStyle("CustomError");
```

---

About this:

> how can I import all the modules at once instead of importing them separately for every module from the same file

I suspect you meant *"...for every **component** from the same file..."* In case you're worried about the module being imported multiple times, don't be. Regardless of how many times you call `import("./style")`, the module is only imported **once**. If the module is already imported or being imported the second/third/fourth time you call `import()`, the promises from those calls just get fulfilled with the same module namespace object that the first one did/will. That's *effectively* guaranteed by [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#sec-hostimportmoduledynamically) where it says:

> Any subsequent call to HostResolveImportedModule after FinishDynamicImport has completed, given the arguments *referencingScriptOrModule* and *specifier*, must return a normal completion containing a module which has already been evaluated, i.e. whose Evaluate concrete method has already been called and returned a normal completion.

Comment: This will work, but be careful because the `() => import("./style")` part should remain static (you can't replace `"./style"` with a variable) otherwise the bundler won't work.

Comment: @Sheraff - Indeed, I was careful to use a string literal there. As you say, bundlers don't like *truly* dynamic imports, just ones that are optional/delayed. :-D (And fair enough.)